# What would be a good strategy for a variable for prefixing a static resource?

Tags: php, scalability, static-resource

We are scaling a website and we would like to plan for the future where we may want to host our images in a sub-domain (or perhaps even a separate domain altogether, e.g. a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)). We currently reference images in our HTML/PHP code using the following HTML:

```
<img src="/images/ourlogo.jpg" alt="Our Logo" />
```

I was thinking of starting a company convention to move to:

```
<img src="<?php echo STAT_IMG;?>ourlogo.jpg" alt="Our Logo" />
```

where STAT_IMG is a global PHP constant, which would be initially defined to be identical to the current situation, i.e.

```
define('STAT_IMG', '/images/');
```

but could later be changed to something such as:

```
define('STAT_IMG', 'http://www.superfastcdn.com/');
```

Will I run into any issues doing this?

Things I have already thought about:

- I can see there'll be many more string appends in the code base - but I don't expect it'll be noticeable in terms of performance.
- It makes the code uglier (*especially in my example where PHP and HTML have been mixed*).
- One issue is that sometimes you need to explicitly use https for images (or vice version). For example, if you put images in a email, many clients (e.g. gmail) use the https protocol, so resources referencing http (*i.e. unencrypted protocol*) will generate a mixed content warning in some browsers (e.g. IE). [This article from encosia](http://encosia.com/2011/01/19/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/) has a idea for working around this by defining `STAT_IMG` as "protocol-less", e.g. `define('STAT_IMG', '//www.superfastcdn.com/');`. I hope their idea works.

  - We may need a few other constants to explicitly define the protocol e.g. `define('STAT_IMGS', 'https://www.example.com/images/');` and `define('STAT_IMGNS', 'http://www.example.com/images/');` in addition to the previous non-absolute version (`define('STAT_IMG', '/images/');`).
- I will need to apply the same strategy to other static resources such as javascript and CSS stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need is a function -- that's how this tends to be handled in frameworks like Rails, Symfony, and Django.  In general, encapsulating logic is a good idea, so you don't find yourself having to update more than place for a given design change.

For starters, you could put this in a location common across all templates:

```
<?

$my_domain = "something.com";

function static_url($relative_path, $SSL=false) {
  $prefix = $SSL ? 'https' : 'http';
  return "{$prefix}://{$my_domain}{$relative_path}";
}
```

Then, you could put this a your template:

```
<img src="<?=static_url('images/ourlogo.jpg'); ?>" />
```

Or, if you need https:

```
<img src="<?=static_url('images/ourlogo.jpg', true); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks - the extra flexibility of the function is a good idea. The only issue is that I'd need to make sure that every page includes the php file that defines the function - I guess that isn't a big issue given that we could use a autoloader technique such as `spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');`

Comment: Nice :)  It'll definitely benefit you to have common functions across your PHP templates.  Some handy homemade functions I find myself using a lot include:  `truncate`, `pad`, and `simple_table` (this last one turns a two-dimensional PHP array into an HTML table)